# h2o.ai / h2o.automl: Categorical variable out of bounds

Tags: r, h2o

I am using h2o.automl to build a model for the [Kaggle House Prices dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data).

When trying to predict results using the model trained on the test data, I get the following error:

```
Error: DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321:
'Categorical value out of bounds, got 15, next cat starts at 40',
caused by java.lang.AssertionError: Categorical value out of bounds,
got 15, next cat starts at 40
```

**How can I find out what variable this relates to?**

Comment: Thanks for the report, can you provide a reproducible example? I know you can't host kaggle datasets so it can't be fully "copy-paste" reproducible, but if you can provide the code you used that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for jumping on this, @ErinLeDell. I hope this helps: https://github.com/matt-jay/h2o-cat-issues

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue for h2o: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6266.

Comment: Yep, this is a bug with the Stacked Ensemble function... will be fixed soon.

Comment: I get a similar error, even with option `exclude_algos = c("StackedEnsemble")`. Removing high cardinality categorical features helps.

Answer (score 0):

h2o.ai is really making me crazy, with AutoML, predict always have `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -22 out of bounds for length 630` error.
trained with `train.csv`, predict with `train.csv` is ok, predict with `predict.csv` is always error!
`train.csv` and `predict.csv` have the same headers and in order.